# start second activity and fail to back to first activity

Tags: android, activity-stack

Assume that I completely quite my application. (no more activity stack)

However, the notification arrive and user will be navigate to second activity when click

The question is how can I make an second activity back to first activity (lancher) and then exit

instead of exit directly if press back button (because it doesn't have any stack)!?

**NOTIFICATION WHICH NAVIGATE TO SECOND ACT.**

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_social_person)
                        .setContentTitle("AIR° TRACKING MODE!")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setOngoing(true);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                new Intent(this, Activity_Second.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(GM.NOTIFICATION_TRACKING_MODE, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaskStackBuilder is the best choice, I think so...

```
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Activity_One.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

and in the Manifest:

work  for API <  16

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity_Second">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".Activity_One" />
    </activity>
```

for API > 16

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity_Second"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity_One" />
```

sorry. when use TaskStackBuilder, remember to edit you PendingIntent like this:

```
     PendingIntent contentIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
```

Comment: why compiler said addPareantStack, addNextIntent requires api 16 current min is api 14. Is it okay to use for api14??

Comment: do you check your minSDK in AdnroidManifest? And what is you targetSDK?

Comment: I put this > import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder; and compiler was clean.

Comment: :). You can read more about TaskStackBuilder to clean you knowled about this,"why TaskStackBuiler, how it run?"
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

You can add that in `onBackPressed()` Override method from `Activity_Second.class` to `Activity_First.class`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent ide = new Intent(this, Activity_First.class);
    ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(ide);

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **TaskStackBuilder**:

Read this [document](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Hariharan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26422305/208273) is correct, except for the flag.  Use this code instead:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent ide = new Intent(this, Activity_First.class);
    ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(ide);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TaskStackBuilder` is the most appropriate for complex activity
Easy to manage... if you know how !

**Navigate Code from Notification & add proper back stack**

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_social_person)
                    .setContentTitle("AIR° TRACKING MODE!")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setOngoing(true);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            //addParentStack is destination class not its parent class
            //it will refer parent class from what you define in XML
            .addParentStack(Activity_TrackingMode.class)
            //and provide intent for destination class
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, Activity_TrackingMode.class))
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(GM.NOTIFICATION_TRACKING_MODE, mBuilder.build());
```

**Example of XML in AndroidManifest**

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity_TrackingMode"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:parentActivityName=".Activity_Screen1">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Activity_Screen1" />
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**PS.** > `import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;` //for support API below 16